# Could not add Service Provider. You might be entering a duplicate Service Provider

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I am new to WSO2 `Identity Server` (IS). I've created few `Service Providers` (SP) named as eclipse-rest and wpfs-rest as a Service Provider ID.

For eclipse-rest, I created Issuer "`eclipse`" and for wpfs-rest I created issuer "`wpfs`", but unfortunately it's gets deleted from someone. Now again when I am using same name "eclipse" for issuer it's `"Could not add Service Provider. You might be entering a duplicate Service Provider"`

Please help me I am really frustrated to solve this error.

Answer (score 8):

When u delete a service provide, the issuer ID entry is not deleted from the registry. So we cannot enter the same issuer ID again for a next SP. So what you can do is go to `https://localhost:9443/carbon/sso-saml/manage_service_providers.jsp` Then  the related issuer Id entry listed and delete that entry. Then try again to add the same SP again. You will be ok now.

Comment: thank you its working, but how we can navigate using ui instead of direct url

Answer (score 0):

Which WSO2 IS version are you using?

This issue has been fixed in IS 5.0.0-Alpha release. you can find more details on this from [here](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-2089).

Comment: I am using wso2is-5.0.0

Comment: You should get this error message only if you have already registered any other SP with the issuer as "eclipse". Please check all the registered SPs and see if any of them have the issuer as "eclipse".

Comment: Hi Udani - By when we can expect latest version to be available for downloads? We really need it.  Regards, Neha

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully got around this in the past by deleting the SP fully (taking the general good practice approach with WSO2 of clicking "update" or "save" whenever you see it.)

I'm not entirely sure what exactly you can't add but if you don't have a SP to delete, try creating one with the same name and then deleting it before adding the issuer you're having trouble with.

You can also try adding an issuer with the problem name to a test SP, then deleting that SP.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error message when I deleted a SP and tried to re-add it-

Since none of the above worked for me, I had to hack the wso2-DB for this.

first create a new SP with the admin console. I could create the SP, the error come as I tried to add "SAML2 SSO Config" to it.

then hack the DB

```
     use regdb;
     select * FROM SP_APP;
```

note your newly added ID

```
    

    SELECT INBOUND_AUTH_KEY, INBOUND_AUTH_TYPE, APP_ID  FROM SP_INBOUND_AUTH;

    | sp1-entity-id | samlsso           |     12 |
    |               | passivests        |     12 |
    |               | openid            |     12 |
    |               | passivests        |     16 |
    |               | openid            |     16 |
```

The admin console allready created some empty config lines for the new SP (id=16). I was trying to add samlsso config to the SP, so I inserted a new DB row with an unique SP-Entity-ID

```
    | ENTITY_ID     | samlsso           |     16 |
```

I went back to the admin console, and the configuration was there!

good luck!